# Distinct, count and sort in one sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

This is my first question on stackoverflow, welcome everybody.

I have a table:

```
id   fk_user
1      1
2      1
3      3
4      2
5      3
```

And I would like to prepare an SQL query witch returns `fk_user` sorted by the number of occurrences in that table. For instance:

`fk_user 1` occurs 3 times, so it will be first.
`fk_user 2` occurs once, so it will be last.
`fk_user 3` occurs twice, so it will be the second.

Result of that query should be:

```
fk_user
1
3
2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select fk_user from 
xxx
group by fk_user
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: @Marco. Thaks guys. It's run. I Have to little reputation to click "this answer is  useful", but it is:)

Comment: @pmajcher: but you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT fk_user FROM your_table
GROUP BY fk_user 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```